# Threads e interrupt();

Tags: java, thread, websocket

Gostaria de saber como posso **pausar minha Thread** de maneira eficiente e correta com o **metodo Interrupt();** estou com uma parte da minha classe que iniciei, mas gostaria de pausa-la.

Meu projeto consiste em um **websocket**, que eu gostaria que **parasse**, mas não obtive sucesso nas minha pesquisas, então resolvi coloca-lo **dentro de um thread** e pausar dessa forma, gostaria de uma ajuda.

Segue o **código** a baixo:

```
public Runnable servidor = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new ServidorExt(8080).start();
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(painelUsuarios.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };
```

Estou iniciando pelo comando ***" new Thread(servidor).start(); "*** e tentando parar o mesmo pelo ***" new Thread(servidor).interrupt(); "***.

Comment: Você está criando uma nova `thread`, por isso não está conseguindo. Utilize `Thread t = new Thread(servidor); t.start();` e para interromper `t.interrupt();`

Comment: Mas a função para interromper funciona normalmente, não há necessidades de complementos?

Comment: Exemplo, utilizei o exemplo que você deu, mas a classe não para, tanto que meu websocket continua aberto da mesma forma. @ValdeirPsr

Comment: Não precisa de parâmetros, você também pode usar `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`

Comment: Tentei executar os 2 métodos de uma vez, iniciando e finalizando logo em seguida, mas recebo um erro: " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException " @ValdeirPsr

Comment: Ele não finaliza a thread, o websocket continua aberto e funcionando normalmente. @ValdeirPsr